# JSONP ReferenceError: Can't find variable

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I'm trying to set up an incredibly simple JSONP callback.

```
<script src="http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/?callback=data&format=jsonp">
   var response = data()
   console.log response
</script>
```

This gives me the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data

JSONP has been enabled per [this request on Github](https://github.com/ingenology/mars_weather_api/issues/2)

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSONP, you're supposed to define the callback function in a script on the client page before it tries to load the remote script. The server sends back Javascript that calls this function with the JSON data.

Also, you can't put code in a `<script>` tag that has a `src` attribute.

So your code should look like:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function data(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
</script>
<script src="http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/?callback=data&format=jsonp"></script>
```